# TeXlipse spell-check configuration

Tags: eclipse, configuration, spell-checking

I'm turning kind of desperate looking for a way to enable spell checking in TeXlipse. Of the application itself I am very fond. I've tried things I found here and on other forums, and on the user manual (http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/spelling.html), but I can't find *clear instructions to configure* spell checking, i.e. what path directory to choose, where can I find .dict files,… I mean step-by-step instructions from the beginning to the end. The User Manual entry is too vague for me.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.6, Eclipse 3.6.2, TeXlipse 1.4.1.

Answer (score 15):

The answers *are* in the manual:
http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/manual/spelling.html

1. Get the dictionaries here: [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/files/)
2. Save them wherever you want. Could be `/Users/your_name/documents/dictionaries`, for example.
3. Enable 'Use built in spell checker' in the Texlipse options in eclipse.
4. Set both directories to whatever you used above.
5. Enable eclipse's own spellchecker, if it isn't already.
6. Restart the IDE.

I had a little trouble getting it to work nicely; I keep getting the following error message in the console. There are about 10 posts on the texlipse forum about it with no answers, so presumably it's not a big deal.

```
running: null
Error running spell checker
```

Comment: Texlipse spelling errors do not show up in problems view of eclipse 3.7,even whenthe problems view filter is set to "Show A>ll"4

Comment: The lack of standard location for the dictionaries is confusing. It's not too elegant for every user to save a copy of the main dictionary under his home directory. Also, the user dictionary would ideally reside under the project directory so that every contributor would receive it, but this is not possible because there's no project specific setting for the directory.

Comment: after i did what you wrote, the whole textclipse plugin won't work anymore --- Plug-in net.sourceforge.texlipse was unable to load class net.sourceforge.texlipse.editor.TexEditor.

Comment: @Dukeatcoding: the instructions worked fine for me with Eclipse Juno and TeXlipse 1.5. However, I experience these crashes of TeXlipse every few month without being able to tie it to a cause. Reinstalling the plugin usually helps.

Comment: It's not said in the manual that you have to select the Latex spell checker from Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Spelling. The error message you get is because Latex > Check Spelling tries to call aspell but the path isn't configured. When configured this way, Jazzy spell checker is used automatically, and you don't have to run the Check Spelling command

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that you set the language for the project under

> Properties > Latex Project Properties > Language setting to "en"

after telling it to use the built in spell checker in

> Preferences > Texlipse

Answer (score 1):

For me, it turned out to be related to file extensions. I pointed the texlipse spell checker to the same directory that eclipse stores its dictionaries and it didn't work. Then I made my own directory and generated my own dictionary using aspell (as mentioned in the texlipse FAQ), but this time I used a simple "dict" extension instead of the "dictionary" as in the Eclipse installation and it worked.

Comment: Thank you. I had it named ".dic"