# Spellchecking doesn't work in eclipse with Texlipse

Tags: eclipse, spell-checking, texlipse

I have installed eclipse Kepler with Texlipse. However, the spellchecking doesn't seem to work. It doesn't mark any words.

I have already:

- enabled spellchecking both in the general and the texlipse preferences
- downloaded the dictionaries from http://sourceforge.net/projects/texlipse/files/dictionaries/ and set their directory as the directory for both main and user dictionaries in the Texlipse-preferences
- copied the wordlists from the eclipse installation and changed the extension to ".dic" and ".dict"
- restarted eclipse several times

I am also unable to find an option to start a spellcheck for the whole document, like there usually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems with the TeXlipse spellchecker. To fix it I followed the instructions from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5736974/2920749
Additionally, I set the language code to en in the project settings as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7064110/2920749.
However, spellchecking still did not work for me under Ubuntu 12.04.
I had to switch to a monospaced font to get it working.

Also make sure that the dictionaries are uncompressed.
Check that all dictionary files are readable and that you have write access to the user-defined dictionary.

Comment: Your _spellchecker_ didn't work until you _switched fonts_, is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, I was refering to the spellchecker. I just made this obvious above.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing that did the trick for me was, after having done the same as you did, to go to

```
Project > Properties > Latex Project Properties
```

and set the language setting (last entry on the right) to `en' (or whatever language you need).

The interesting thing is that in my case everything worked fine until one day, and suddenly, the project stopped doing the spelling, until I set this value, which turned it on again. I am quite sure that I did not remove this property in the last few days unless there is a secrete short-cut that I mistakenly pressed. So, very weird.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I was using Inconsolata font (that I find awesome) and spell check didn't underline wrong words. I then changed font to Dejavu Sans Mono and the underline appeared.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the font worked, but I found another solution changing the markup type in `Window > Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors > Annotations > Spelling errors`

There, you can check the `Text as` checkbox, select a different option (e.g. highlighted) and click apply to see the changes.
For some reason, in my case, some options are not displaying and some others yes.